# history push is pushing two times same key

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

English is not my language so there might be mistakes, i'm beginner programmer(react hooks), my form(antd) data is moving in url, everything is working fine except going back and changing form input value to another then going again forward, i can see there is now two times same key but different value, my point is now there is for example 'name=james' and 'name=susan', but i want to have just one 'name' and it should be the latest, should i be pushing differently? below is also a picture i made about this, if it helps to understand. when   console.log(query); it shows both 'names'

Next page function comes from here :
< Form onFinish={nextPage}>
< / Form>

i'm going back from page b to page a like this:

```js
const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];

  const handleclick = () => {
    history.push(`/pagea/${custId}?${query}`);
  };
```

history push in nextPage function is like this

```js
const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];

  const nextPage = (order: rRequest) => {

    history.push(`/customers/${custId}?${query}&name=${order.name}`);
 };
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share a minimal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) which reproduces the issue?

Comment: But bearing in mind that all the details need to be in your post - show the [mcve] code in your post, with the codesandbox link as "runnable example", not as "only way to find out what you mean".

Comment: I think your issue comes from the whole query u are attaching, It might do you good to assign those query params instead of cutting it out from the url that way you have fresh copies everytime

Comment: could you implement some working example using my code? if need anything to know i will anwer, or some specifc code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];
var qry = "";
if (query) {
  qry = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < qry.length; i++) {
    var curr = qry[i].split("=");
    if (curr[0] == "name") {
      qry.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  qry = qry.join("&");
}

const nextPage = (order: rRequest) => {
  history.push(`/customers/${custId}?${qry}&name=${order.name}`);
};
```

Comment: On which string?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: May be you already using variable `i` before this code?

Comment: i messed `i < qry.length`

Comment: hey i got it working like this const query = window.location.toString().split("?")[1];
  var qry: any;
  if (query) {
    qry = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < qry.length; i++) {
      var curr = qry[i].split("=");
      if (curr[0] == "name") {
        qry.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }

Comment: one question i got, i had many inputs in my form, it fixed also those others, why ? you have there 'name'

Comment: I just search attribute name in query string, and if there is attribute name i delete it

Comment: but in   console.log(query);
i can see all those other names it does not delete them ? it just accept latest ?

Comment: variable `qry` has changed use `console.log(qry)`

Comment: could you help with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110856/multiple-customer-different-ids