# multiple customer different id's

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, antd

React beginner here, English is not my mother language so sorry for mistakes, here I have an input, button and dropdown(select options), 'value' represents id and 'text' represents customer, here I have a problem, when user clicks customer 'james' (I have two of them) it will choose both of them, how to correct it that it should choose that which is clicked? everything is working correctly if I don't have users with the same name, my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Button, AutoComplete } from "antd";
import { CloseOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

export default function EventsSection() {
  const autoControl = React.createRef();
  const defaultOptions = [
    { value: "1", text: "Nicholas" },
    { value: "2", text: "Alex" },
    { value: "3", text: "Putin" },
    { value: "4", text: "Biden" },
    { value: "5", text: "Peka" },
    { value: "6", text: "James" },
    { value: "7", text: "James" }
  ];
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(defaultOptions);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(true);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("");

  const { Option } = AutoComplete;

  const changeHandler = (text) => {
    setSelectedOption(text);
    if (options.filter((f) => f.text === text).length) {
      setSelectedValue(options.filter((f) => f.text === text)[0].value);
    } else {
      setOptions(defaultOptions);
      setSelectedValue("");
    }
    if (!text || !text.length) {
      setDropdownOpen(false);
      autoControl.current.blur();
    }
  };

  function handleClick() {
    const id = selectedValue;
    console.log(`value: ${id}, text: ${selectedOption}`);
    //history.push(`/customer/${id}`);
  }

  function onClear() {
    changeHandler("");
  }

  function onFocusChange() {
    if (!dropdownOpen) setDropdownOpen(true);
  }

  function onSearch(value) {
    setOptions(
      defaultOptions.filter((f) =>
        f.text.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {/* when found in search i want this button take to  'onChange' address also*/}
      <button disabled={!selectedValue} onClick={handleClick}>
        click me when found in search
      </button>
      <AutoComplete
        ref={autoControl}
        open={dropdownOpen}
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Search..."
        listHeight={220}
        onSearch={(e) => onSearch(e)}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        value={selectedOption}
        onFocus={onFocusChange}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <Option key={option.value} value={option.text}>
            {option.text}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </AutoComplete>
      <Button
        disabled={!selectedValue}
        onClick={onClear}
        type="primary"
        icon={<CloseOutlined />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<EventsSection />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the autocomplete would allow you to set the display/value members separately, but I'm not very familiar with these components so instead I did a small refactor on this page to change the way you're handling the state of the autocomplete, but now it works like you want it to.

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bhaskara-m2vm2?file=/src/component.js

`const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({ value: "", text: "" });`

```
<AutoComplete
        ref={autoControl}
        open={dropdownOpen}
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Search..."
        listHeight={220}
        onSearch={(e) => onSearch(e)}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        value={selectedOption.text}
        onFocus={onFocusChange}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.text}
          </Option>
        ))}
```

I also changed the change handler to include `option` as a parameter and am setting the selectedOption state based on that.

Comment: now those other functionality is not working like 'CloseOutlined', it should work like this : https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4150-forked-4lnb3?file=/index.js:158-171             could you make those other work also, with your code ?

Comment: The clear button should be working in my example now.
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bhaskara-m2vm2?file=/src/component.js

Comment: why this isnt working ?   <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.text}
            <br></br>
            {option.value}

          </Option>

Comment: in dropdown i want to have 'text' and 'value' under each other it is working but in input it gives Putin,[object Object],3, how to get rid of object object ?

Comment: so in this case you can actually just do another easy refactor, set the value={option.text} and then change the children to be whatever you want--you will want to stop referencing the children in the change handler.

You can do something like this:
`<Option key={option.value} value={option.text}>
  {option.text} <br /> {option.value}
</Option>`

and then your change handler can be simplified to:
`const changeHandler = (_, option) => {
  setSelectedOption({ value: option.key, text: option.value });
};`
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bhaskara-m2vm2?file=/src/component.js:407-441

Comment: try codesandbox you provided in comment and choose from dropdown 'james 6' in console you can see that it is not picking that instead it picks other james from list...

Comment: try codesandbox you provided in comment and choose from dropdown 'james 6' in console you can see that it is not picking that instead it picks other james from list...

Answer (score 0):

Hey so in order to fix this I think all you need to do is set the Option component's value to the unique key in your list of options.

for example:

```
<Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
  {option.text}
</Option>
```

The goal should be to have your autocomplete display `option.text` but set the value and state based on `option.value`.

Comment: if i do like that it would display values in input field instead of customer names

Comment: Ah you're right, my mistake, please refer to my other comment for a better fix.